# What is the type of a class which implements a interface

Tags: java, types

can anybody tell me if the  assignment l4 & l5 is correct and why ?  e.g

`ArrayList` and `List` implement `Serializable` interface.

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<? super Serializable> l4 = list1 ;
ArrayList<Serializable> l5 = list1 ;
```

`String` is a class which implements `Serializable` interface, then String is called "a subtype of `Serializable`" or "a type of `Serializable`"?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Neither is correct.

Line 4 will not work because `String` is not a supertype of `Serializable`, it's a *subtype*.
Line 5 will not work because `ArrayList<String>` is not a subtype of `ArrayList<Serializable>`.

This will work though:

```
ArrayList<? extends Serializable> l6 = list1; // because String implements Serializable
List<String> l7 = list1; // because ArrayList implements List
List<? extends Serializable> l8 - list1; // both of the above
```

Comment: Thanks first. In api states that String implements Serializable ,not extends. So i do not know of String is a type of Serializable or a subtyp of Serializable?

Comment: Ok, updated to say 'implements'.  For these things it really doesn't make a difference though.  In general, we only use the term 'subtype' if we extends a class, not implement an interface.  The term 'type of' is only used that a class is the type of an object; so String is the type of `"Hello"`.  The most proper thing to say is that String implements Serializable.